# Get Chart Axis Value

Tags: vba, excel

I realise you can set the axis of a graph in VBA using

```
.MaximumScale = 
.MinimumScale =
```

**Is there a way to get the axis value?**

I ask this because it would make it easier to automate a process that gets the axis of a chart, then adds a month to it (without setting the graph axis to automatic).

P.S.

I recorded a macro of changing the axis dates and it set the date values as a number like *40148* or *41609*. What is this?

Comment: 40148 and 41609 are dates in numeric format. Those numbers correspond to Dec 1, 2009 and Dec 1, 2013 respectively. You can find that out by changing the format of the cell with the numbers to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to step through the following snippet of code. It shows how to find Y axis value and how to change it. See some comments inside.

**1st attempt for chart embedded in worksheet**

```
Sub test_chart()

'get the chart for activesheet
    Dim myCHR As Chart
    Set myCHR = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart

'get Y axis of the chart
    Dim myYA As Axis
    Set myYA = myCHR.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue)

'get the value
    Debug.Print myYA.MaximumScale
    Debug.Print myYA.MinimumScale

'the same in almost one line
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlValue)
        Debug.Print .MaximumScale
        Debug.Print .MinimumScale
        'change the value
        .MaximumScale = 10
    End With
End Sub
```

**2nd attempt for chart being separate sheet**

```
Sub test_sheet_chart()

'get the chart for activesheet
    Dim myCHR As Chart
    Set myCHR = Sheets("All SIN 10 Pubs - Unique Users")

'get Y axis of the chart
    Dim myYA As Axis
    Set myYA = myCHR.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue)

'get the value
    Debug.Print myYA.MaximumScale
    Debug.Print myYA.MinimumScale

'the same in almost one line
    With Sheets("All SIN 10 Pubs - Unique Users").Axes(xlValue)
        Debug.Print .MaximumScale
        Debug.Print .MinimumScale
        'change the value
        .MaximumScale = 10
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this work with you? I receive an 'Application-defined or object defined error' on 'Set myCHR = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart'

Comment: question- do you have any chart floating on the activesheet? or you have sheet chart (the chart is sheet itself)?

Comment: The sheet is the chart. This is how a recorded Macro looks selecting the chart:

    _Sheets("All SIN 10 Pubs - Unique Users").Select
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select_

Comment: @JakkyD, see second solution in my answer.