# VBA to format the charts

Tags: vba, excel

I have an sheet where I am using codes to generate a Pivot table, and a 100stackedcolumn chart.

when I generate these charts, I get my Y axis in percentange. I wanted to convert this percentage into absolute numbers.

How can I do this with VBA ? I am new to VBA, I used record macro, but I would like to have an code, apart from macros, which could help me to do it everytime.

here is the macro,which i recorded.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Application.WindowState = xlNormal
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(297, xlColumnStacked100).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Cat_Pivot!$A$3:$F$19")
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    Selection.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "Standard"
End Sub
```

Comment: "...but I would like to have an code, apart from macros, which could help me to do it everytime" - If you want this to occur automatically, then you'll need VBA (I'm assuming you can't just set the data format to what you want, and the chart doesn't automatically reflect that format).  If you've used the Macro Recorder, you should have some code. Can you please post that and what attempts you've made?

Comment: Yeah sure, I tried to do it manualy and recorded the macro.

Comment: @BruceWayne I have edited the post .

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to fetch the Y axis of a chart using vba code, this subject was allready addressed in a previous post, see here : [Get Chart Axis Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21112295/get-chart-axis-value)

From there you can simply convert it into an absolute value (hard for me to describe this stop considering you have no code to show) :)

Comment: @ Antoine.D In the link you suggested, it is giving Type mismatch error.

Comment: Have you tried both solution in the answer? Usually, a type mismatch error can be solved easily by adapting your code architecture to the function

Comment: ya, I tried both the solution,the first solution gives an application defined error and other gives type mismatch.

Comment: how do i adapt my core architecture to function ?

Comment: I already have my code generating the Chart, i just now Need to Change the axis. I am sorry, i am completely new to VBA.

Comment: I can't tell you from my perspective what causes the problem, have you tried a step by step debuging?

Comment: ya, i tried. The error occurs in  Set myCHR = Sheets("Pivot")

Comment: myCHR is a chart type, not a Sheets type :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147758/discussion-between-mikz-and-antoine-d).